# Redshift SQL Rolling SUM OVER last 3 ids by timestamp (with every id having multiple rows)

Tags: sql, function, window, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

So I have a table called orders in redshift SQL similar to this

| timestamp | customer_id | order_id | category | brand | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Computer | Apple | 4 |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Mobile | Apple | 2 |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Computer | HP | 3 |
| 2020-10-24 00:15:38.000000 | John | 8321 | Computer | HP | 4 |
| 2020-10-24 00:15:38.000000 | John | 8312 | Mobile | Apple | 3 |
| 2021-05-04 02:27:18.000000 | John | 3214 | Mobile | Apple | 3 |
| 2021-05-04 02:27:18.000000 | John | 3124 | Computer | Apple | 5 |

*Note that the order_id has no particular timebased sequence and customer_id is actually a unique ID and not a name*

What I want to do is SIMILAR to what a window function like this would do:

```
SELECT timestamp,
 customer_id,
 order_id,
 category,
 brand
SUM(quantity) 
OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS 3 PRECEDING) as rolling_sum 
FROM order
```

BUT instead of doing a running SUM on current and previous two rows, I want to SUM current id and previous 2 order_ids and do that for every coming order_id, so not just last 3 or first 3 orders, but last 3 orders for every order after as a customer_id might have 100 orders etc.

To basically get this output

| timestamp | customer_name | order_id | category | brand | quantity | rolling_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Computer | Apple | 4 | 4 |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Mobile | Apple | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-09-02 09:53:59.000000 | John | 4213 | Computer | HP | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-10-24 00:15:38.000000 | John | 8321 | Computer | Apple | 0 | 4 |
| 2020-10-24 00:15:38.000000 | John | 8321 | Computer | HP | 4 | 7 |
| 2020-10-24 00:15:38.000000 | John | 8312 | Mobile | Apple | 3 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 02:27:18.000000 | John | 3124 | Mobile | Apple | 3 | 8 |
| 2021-05-04 02:27:18.000000 | John | 3124 | Computer | Apple | 5 | 9 |
| 2021-05-04 02:27:18.000000 | John | 3124 | Computer | HP | 0 | 7 |

From what I understand this isn't possible with a regular window function and needs combination between JOINS and common table expressions, so if you're able to see a solution of any kind I would be very happy to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest summarizing and using window functions:

```
select orderid, customerid, timestamp, sum(quantity) as quantity,
       sum(sum(quantity)) over (partition by customerid order by timestamp rows between 3 preceding and current row) as running_quantity_4
from orders
group by orderid, customerid, timestamp;
```

Then `join` this back to your table:

```
select o.*, oct.running_quantity_4
from orders o join
     (select orderid, customerid, timestamp, sum(quantity) as quantity,
             sum(sum(quantity)) over (partition by customerid order by timestamp rows between 3 preceding and current row) as running_quantity_4
      from orders
      group by orderid, customerid, timestamp
     ) oct
     on oct.orderid = o.orderid;
```

Comment: That won't solve the issue as I don't want to sum preceding rows, but rather sum preceding order id's and the id's will have varying number of rows. Also the category and brand must be included for my end goal.

Comment: @Timo . . . This is summing the orders *after* aggregation.  Hence, it is a fixed number of rows.  Clever, eh?

Comment: Ahh I see what you did and that is clever! However it won't fully do what I need it to, as I need it to attribute the Sum of quantity to the right attribute and brand grouping, which won't be done by order_id as that includes several rows and won't be fully acknowledged. There is also an order row ID  if that's of any help  Thank you nonetheless, got me thinking 

Comment: @Timo . . . This answers the question asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: I'm sorry Gordon but no. This does not answer the initial question at all, you mistook the question I asked for something else. I've solved the issue by creating a row for all the brands that a customer has ever purchased historically for every order_id and if that order_id didn't include that brand, the quantity would be 0, that way I could actually do a rolling 3 order sum for every brand.

Comment: @Timo . . . I have no idea what "brand" has to do with the question asked here, but I am happy that you have solved your problem.